# VMware Tool doesn't install

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I have a virtual machine with Windows XP. And my host computer is on Windows 10. I'm using VMware version 14. I'm trying to setup a shared folder for my virtual machine and faced with an issue that Shared Folder doesn't appear on my VM. I've started investigate and found that VMware Tools are not installed on my VM. When I go Player -> Manage -> Install VMware Tools -> nothing happens. I don't see any pop-up windows with installation. It seems like virtual CD is inserted but nothing more. I can't see it in My Computer.
What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Can you ping your XP VM from your Host Win 10 Machine?
If you couldn't ping your XP VM IP from your host machine, turn your firewall off on both machines and try to ping again.

Did you turn on your network discovery on your Windows 10 Machine and XP Machine?
If you can ping your VM from Host machine, turn on file and print sharing settings.